# Destructuring on List for more than 5 elements

Tags: json, kotlin

I have a JSON array that holds more than five elements.

Trying to do the following:

```
val (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) = JSON.array()
```

This will throw the following erros:

```
Kotlin: Destructuring declaration initializer of type List<Letter> must have a 'component6()' function

Kotlin: Destructuring declaration initializer of type List<Letter> must have a 'component7()' function
```

I do not want to write the following code:

```
val a = array[0], b = array[1] ...
```

Comment: looks like your JSON array doesn't have element 6 and element 7 that you are trying to assign

Comment: @vlad324 First of all, it is a compile time error and secondly you can look at the source code of `List` and will find out that there are only five **componentN** functions.

Comment: Why the *Java* tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by declaring additional **componentN** functions:

```
operator fun List<Any>.component6() = this[5]
operator fun List<Any>.component7() = this[6]
```

#### Note

If we want to use *Destructuring declaration*, we need to mark the class with the `data` keyword or provide `component1, component2 ... componentN` functions for as many values as we want to get.

For the **List** class, the generated `_Collections.kt` file **only** contains the `compenentN` functions until `compenent5`.

Comment: Note: for using `Destructuring declaration` you need to mark the class with `data` keyword or the class should have component1,component2…..componentN methods for each variable you want to get.

Comment: @DennisVash It is a `List`. The `generated/_Collections.kt` file only contains the **compenentN** functions until `compenent5` for me.

Comment: yep, I just thought you should mention it in the answer for further look ups

Answer (score 1):

The `componentX` functions for `List` are defined within the `kotlin.collections` package. You will [find it](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) for components 1 to 5. If you want to have more, you can create extension functions like this, which is based on the actual implementations that are provided already:

```
/**
 * Returns 6th *element* from the collection.
 */
inline operator fun <T> List<T>.component6(): T = get(5)
```

Comment: Nice to see that my solution was probably the correct one, but otherwise pretty sad that the implementation of this feature is not handled more nicely.